# How to keep printing in python until input is given

Tags: python

I am trying to print out items from a list of text in python. My goal is to make it stop printing when I type stop. My current code is like this

```
for i in text:
        print(i,end=" ")
        inp=input("")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if inp=="stop":
            break
```

However, this keeps needing me to click enter to get to the next block of text. Is there a way to keep printing out words every 0.5 seconds without having to click enter?

Comment: May need to use two threads, one for printing, one for user input.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be achieved. But I guess the following may do what you want. When you press ctrl+c , you will break the loop.

```
for i in text:
    try:
        print(k,end=" ") ## I guess it is print(i, end = " ")?
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Comment: I was more looking for a way to take a specific input, probably should have made that more clear

Comment: Never mind, your solution is fine, I am finding it strange why python doesn't let me use the end=" " when in the loop, do you know why?

Comment: I think you can do that. What's your output? And btw you can also use threading as mentioned by @ChickenFeet.

Comment: I also found that stops after print the first element, not sure why

Comment: Never mind, i figured it out. You have to set flushed=True in the print statement to make it work